# How to call a derived class' virtual function from the base class in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual some_type foo();
protected:
    virtual some_type bar();
}

class B : public A
{
protected:
    some_type bar() override;
}

// std::shared_ptr<B> b_ptr;
b_ptr->foo();
```

Where `A::foo` calls `bar`. For some reason that I cannot seem to understand, `A::bar` is being called insted of `B::bar`. Is there any way to ensure `B::bar` is called instead?

EDIT:

```
some_type A::foo() {
    this->bar();
}
```

EDIT 2:
Class was instantiated as A, and then cast to B, hence the shared pointer to B was invalid.

Comment: Calls `bar()` where? Code?

Comment: See edit, `A::foo` calls `bar`.

Comment: @Aspen Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Usually, the only way that `A::foo()` calling `this->bar()` would call `A::bar()` instead of `B::bar()` is if the call to `foo()` is being made in the context of `A`'s constructor or destructor - ie times when `A`'s vtable doesn't point to a `B` object.

Comment: Remy you were correct, investigated and object was created type A not B and was being cast to B elsewhere in the code base.

Comment: Well that cast is a bug in your code. Remove it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If `foo()` calls `bar()` in this way:

```
some_type foo(){ A::bar(); }
```

This is compile time binding, and so the compiler will bind that call to `A::bar()` even if the dynamic type is `B`.

Instead, if `foo()` calls `bar()` in this way:

```
some_type foo(){ this->bar(); /*or just bar(), same thing*/}
```

Then because `bar()` is virtual, the binding will be resolved at runtime, and so it will call the `bar()` function for the dynamic type, thus `B::bar()`.

So this code:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo(){this->bar();};
protected:
    virtual void bar(){cout<<"A";};
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    void bar() override{cout<<"B";};
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<B> b_ptr(new B);
    b_ptr->foo(); // B
}
```

Will print `B`, but this code:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo(){A::bar();};
protected:
    virtual void bar(){cout<<"A";};
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    void bar() override{cout<<"B";};
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<B> b_ptr(new B);
    b_ptr->foo(); // A
}
```

will print `A`

Comment: That is what I thought should happen, but doesn't seem to be the case, looking at the debugger, in foo, this is of type A*, could this be causing the problem?

Comment: @Aspen without a [mcve], there is really no way to tell you for sure why it is not working the way you expect.

Comment: @Aspen try with the examples... probably you are doing something else wrong... can you please post the functions you are using?